# Navigator doesn't Re-render after redux state change in React Navigation 5

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-navigation, redux-thunk, react-navigation-v5

I'm using a stack navigator from react navigation v5 with redux. The stack navigator should render AuthScreen when `isAuthenticated` is `false` and render HomeScreen when `isAuthenticated` changes to `true`.

AppNav.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import AuthScreen from '../screens/AuthScreen';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNav = ({isAuthenticated}) => {
    const [logged, setLogged] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isAuthenticated) {    
            console.log(logged);
          setLogged(true);
        } else {
          setLogged(false);
          console.log(logged);
        }
    },[isAuthenticated])



    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
            {   
                !logged?
                <Stack.Screen name='Auth' component={AuthScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
                :<Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />                
            }
            </Stack.Navigator>                    
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({isAuthenticated}) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppNav)
```

userAction.js

```
import {LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK} from './types';


export const loginWithFacebook = () => async(dispatch) => {        


                dispatch( { type: LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK, payload: {isAuthenticated: true} } );                    

}
```

userReducer.js

```
import {LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK} from '../actions/types.js';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isAuthenticated: false    
};

const userReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case LOGIN_WITH_FACEBOOK: 
            return {...state, ...action.payload};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
export default userReducer
```

rootReducer.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import userReducer from './userReducer';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
 })
 export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by accessing the key of userReducer which is `state.user`.

AppNav.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppNav)
```